# Encriptar contraseña en DjangoRestFramework

Tags: djangorestframework

En un proyecto de DRF, un modelo posee los siguientes campos:

```
class Player (models.Model):

    user_id         = models.UUIDField (primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, blank=True)
    username        = models.CharField (max_length=30, unique=True, null=False)
    email           = models.EmailField (max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)
    password        = models.CharField (max_length=100, null=True)
    is_validated    = models.BooleanField (default=False)
    created         = models.DateField (auto_now_add=True)
    updated         = models.DateField (auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:

        verbose_name = 'player'
        verbose_name_plural = 'players'
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'username'
    ]

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.username
```

Y mi `serializer` es tal cual:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model   = Player
        fields  = ('username', 'email', 'password')

    def create (self, validated_data):
        user = Player(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    def validate_password (self, value):
        if len (value) < 8 or len (value) > 30:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Password length must be between 8 and 30.')
        return value
```

El caso es que el password no aparece encriptado cuando hago `POST`, cosa que sí sucede en el modelo `User`.

**¿A alguien se le ocurre algo?**

¡Gracias!